# z/OS ISPF Editor increasing the rows of the editor

Tags: editor, zos, ispf

After I save a file in a z/OS ISPF it becomes like this

```
 ****** ***** Top of Data ***
 000100 hello
 ****** ***** Bottom of Data ***
```

My Question is, how do I add more lines to this ISPF editor

In other words, how do I make the editor full window again where I can freely type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the I(nsert) line command to insert lines after the line where you type the In - n being the number of lines to insert. The default is 1.

All you really need to know is available by pressing the help key - ususally F1.

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire The Knowledge Center is also a good resource to keep at hand. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.isp/isp.htm

Comment: The key thing to understand about ISPF is it is columnar editor, you can work on individual lines as well as columns.  The command prefix area lets you enter the line commands and the command line lets you act on the file.  You generally add the number of lines you want in what ever place you want.  There are a number of SHARE presentations as well that describe the hidden treasures of ISPF, and here is a link to the editor information directly https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zosbasics/com.ibm.zos.zconcepts/zconcepts_138.htm

Answer (score -1):

I’m guessing the original questioner is new to ISPF, TSO and z/OS in general. So welcome to z/OS!

In general you need to know about prefix commands (like the “i” mentioned above) - which work on individual lines (or groups of lines) - and also how to use the command line.

ISPF Edit becomes second nature to use very quickly.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question and would be better suited as a comment either on the question or on NicC's answer...